# How to add Elements to <li> dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a html like this

```
<button type="button" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="AjoutSousCategorie()"  style="color: bleu;">Ajouter Sous categorie</button>

    <ul class="list">

        <li class="item" ng-repeat="souscategorie in souscategorieData" id="souscategorie{{souscategorieData.idsouscategorie}}">
                {{souscategorie.nomsouscategorie}} <a href="#" ng-click="SupprimerSousCategorie(souscategorie.idsouscategorie)"> <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> </a><a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw" ></i></a> 
            </li>
```

when i click on button('ajouter categorie), i want to append one li tag into the ul tag

i have directive like this, i have tried this but it is not working
it just add a li in ul without content :

```
 $scope.AjoutSousCategorie=function(){
         $scope.souscategorieData.push("bonjour");
}
```

Comment: Well, elements of `souscategorieData` are supposed to be objects with properties, not plain strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `$scope.souscategorieData.push({nomsouscategorie:"bonjour"});` it would show

Comment: dont thank mate, just accept the answer if it solved your issue :-)